# React Native Modal VS Screen

Tags: react-native

I'm working on a RN application which has share and comment features. In Facebook, modals are used to display the comment and share screen contents. In my application I have used seperate screens hence it is bit slower. What is be the better approach to use here?

Comment: Shashika, did you find the answer to that? What would be better solution?

Comment: @Habi, No. I just used screen which is now a mess because there are so many navigations in my app.

Comment: Hahaha Thanks @Shashika. Is there any tips for starters?

Answer (score 0):

Always try to use **SCREEN** with **navigator**. Think about your form modal screen in overall.  May be it more similar on 'screen' then you thought before))

Comment: in addition
In my work a have few task with modals. For instans, I have modal to choose image source 'Camera' or 'Gallery'. If you use 'Modal' . When camera opened from Modal, it will close after Modal close (in IOS)